# i want to pass limit value in my select query through user

Tags: php, mysql, variables, limit

i want to pass limit value in my select query through user,can anybody help me to do this???? thanks in advance![][1]

```
$result = mysql_query("select distinct * from tweet_info ". 
"where MATCH(tweet) ". 
"AGAINST('".$search."')ORDER BY created ", $con);
```

Comment: The last time I passed my value through a user, there were consequences...

Comment: @Fluffeh haha thanks for making me laugh ;)

Comment: The `mysql_` functions are depricated, please use `mysqli_` or PDO instead.

Answer (score 1):

lets just say that the user input is "LimitInput" then :

```
$limit = $_POST['LimitInput'];
$result = mysql_query("select distinct * from tweet_info ". 
"where MATCH(tweet) ". 
"AGAINST('".$search."')ORDER BY created limit 0,".$limit, $con);
```

Comment: this ofcourse if you are using an input named "LimitInput" and your form is on post method

Comment: It is absollutely essential to validate user input! With a bad designed query like this one a user could infiltrate or even delete your whole database! You should use paramerterized queries like supported by PDO instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT * 
                       FROM tweet_info 
                       WHERE MATCH(tweet) 
                       AGAINST('" . $search . "') 
                       ORDER BY created LIMIT 0,1 DESC", $con);
```

Just add a limit to the end, this will grab the first result found.

You shouldn't really be using the mysql_query function anyway, it's depreciated, maybe look into a different method, e.g. mysqli or PDO.